# Camel ProducerTemplate doesn't return HttpResponse Code

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel HTTP component and I am able to send request and receive response.

In failure cases i get exception and if i try to get the HTTP Response code from headers, the response is null.

```
if(exchange.getException() != null ){
   exchange.getException().printStackTrace();
   String responseCode = (String) exchange.getOut().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE);
 }
```

`exchange.getOut()` is NULL and fails with NullPointerException.

How to retrieve the HTTPResponse Code in such cases? Ex: 400, 404, 405.

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: Exchange Pattern used is InOut.

Comment: Yep but you need to call hasOut before you can call getOut

Comment: Ok, will check for hasOut. But my question is how to get the HTTPResponse code in case of exception? And does that different from each Camel Component Ex: Spring-ws, Camel-HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for the http-component you should be able to extract the response code from the Exception.

Perhaps something like this:

```
int code = ((HttpOperationFailedException)exchange.getException()).getStatusCode();
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what even i tried out and found to be working.